# categoryBits/maskbits filter for LiquidFun

Tags: box2d, liquidfun

My game has particle fluids using LiquidFun. Now, I want to have 1 physics object that only collides with particle systems and not with any other Box2D/LiquidFun fixtures (like an invisible shield around the hero that repulses water).

I couldn't find any b2Filter parameters for `ParticleGroup` or `ParticleSystem` in the documentations and according to [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/liquidfun/HTwiNckBBzg) post custom filters doesn't even work.

Comment: Isn't it enough just to make the shield fixture not collide with other fixtures?

Comment: @iforce2d yupp that worked for this problem. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just stating the solution I took:

I created the "invisible shield" and assigned it

```
b2Filter filter;
filter.categoryBits = 0x0001;
filter.maskBits = 0x0000;
```

So, it does not collide with any other Box2D physics object but as LiquidFun particles does collision with everything despite the categoryBits and maskBits, it interacted with liquid and hence worked perfectly for me.

thanks @iforce2d for the direction via comment and this blog post:

http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/collision-filtering